# (Auto-) Update Query after Mutation in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

On a custom react-admin page, I use the [Query](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#query-and-mutation-components) component to fetch and show data and the [withDataProvider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#using-the-withdataprovider-decorator) decorator to save a mutation:

```
export const Controller = ({data, dataProvider}: any) => {
    ...
    dataProvider(UPDATE, "users", { id: data.id, data: {...data, newField: "foo" })
    ...
}

export const Container = ({ data, loading, loaderror, ...props }: any) => {
    const ConnectedController = useMemo(() => withDataProvider(Controller), []);

    if (loading) { return <p data-testid="loading">Loading</p>; }
    if (loaderror) { return <p data-testid="error">Error</p>; }
    return <ConnectedController {...props} data={data} />;
}

export const InjectInitialValues = ({ userid, ...props }: InjectProps) => {
    return <Query type="GET_ONE" resource="users" payload={{ id: userid }}>
        {({ data, loading, error }: { data: object, loading: boolean, error: string }) => (
            <Container {...props} data={data} loading={loading} loaderror={error} />
        )}
    </Query>
};
```

However, after saving the changes, the query component does not trigger a rerender with the new values. Does anyone know how to plug it together such that query rerenders after a change?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is one workaround: The data from the query can be saved as a component state and on an update, one can alter the state. However, this seems not to be the ideal case.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your code? to run re-render you should update state or receive new data via props, also you can run force update, but i am not sure if it will help you. First we should see code

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have a problem in this line, so you set an empty list of dependencies `[]`.

```
const ConnectedController = useMemo(() => withDataProvider(Controller), []);
```

When you specify a dependency list through the last argument of the useMemo hook, it should include all the values used,
which are involved in the React data stream, including the pros, state, and their derivatives.